# Control Win32 process from injected DLL (VC++.NET 2010)

Tags: c++, dll, controls, exe

I've injected a DLL file into another process and I wish to communicate with it though an external EXE. How can I communicate with the injected DLL? :/

Comment: Why is a self-stated beginner starting with DLL injection? Isn't that something for experienced programmers?

Comment: Your description is not clear. What have you achieved so far? Did you manage to inject code into the running process? Can you show us code? How do you tell it's working so far?

Comment: Am I right to assume that you are trying to react to a click on that button *without* modifying the EXE?

Comment: Well not really. I am trying to execute a function within a DLL on a click of a button. The DLL is injected into a different process.

Comment: I just asked because usually DLL injection is done without the target process knowing it (e.g. to "crack" the target process). I wonder why else you would use DLL injection at all (you could just modify the EXE to load the DLL with `LoadLibrary`).

Comment: Oh. Erm..are game trainers allow to be like discuss? O_O Haha. I am new here :P

Comment: @Bawss: Don't know, but Gerald's answer will certainly not help you with that.

Comment: The first thing to look up is the article on how Fraps handles this. If you want sample code, check the EasyHook samples or VoodooShader (disclaimer: project of mine, but has a few forms of hooking).

Comment: Thanks, just to give you all a clear view of what I am trying to achieve:

Comment: @Niklas... my answer would most definitely help him with that. At least as far as triggering some action within the injected DLL from an external process. Doing something useful inside the injected application is another story, and a completely different topic.

Comment: @Gerald: Yeah, I see that now. The original question was quite a different one, there was a lot of editing since.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your question properly, you have injected a DLL to a process and want to communicate with it via some external EXE. You can use the standard methods of [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Interprocess Communication) here. I know a link should not be posted by itself but IPC on Windows is too broad a topic to cover comprehensively without copy and pasting from the linked article.

I have done the same thing as what you are attempting here and used [named piping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#base.using_pipes_for_ipc) and [data copying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#base.using_data_copy_for_ipc) via [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IPC. However, there was a particular reason why I used each form of IPC so we really need to understand more from your problem domain before recommending a single one.

Something unrelated that you are doing is that you are calling CreateThread on a function you have casted to LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, which means it should point to a [ThreadProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback. Your current signature of `void WINAPI ()` does not match the required `DWORD WINAPI (LPVOID)`.

If all your DLL needs to do is to forward messages, it is possible to have it act as a proxy for messages.

- Have the DLL create an invisible window
- Pass the window handle to the source process
- Have the source process dispatch messages to this window
- The DLL will receive these messages and can then forward them to the destination window

However, if this is all you need to do then there is no need to have a DLL in the middle at all. This is why I say we need more information about your problem domain.

If you are trying to have something in the form of an executable which injects a DLL, then communicates with the DLL and the DLL communicates back, you might want to take a look at a [project](http://code.google.com/p/mpi-client/) I worked on a while back. This does exactly that.

Comment: Yes, I've injected a DLL into a process and want to communicate with it through an EXE. :)

Comment: I am considering doing this. :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to communicate between your EXE and the application your DLL has been injected into.

So in your DLL you will need to [spawn a thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that waits for some kind of communication from the EXE. You cannot wait for the event in the DllMain, because that will deadlock the application.

A simple way to do it is to create a [named event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [wait for it to be set in your DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Then in your external EXE, when your button is clicked, you [set the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Threads and events are certainly not the most common way of handling injected DLLs. Hooks/detours usually goes hand in hand with this. If you knew the DLL would be running ahead of time and could properly set up events, you wouldn't need to inject at all.

Comment: @peachykeen: Exactly my thoughts.

Comment: I didn't say it was the most common, I said it was a simple way. Obviously he isn't going to understand detours at this point. One of us may be misunderstanding his problem, but it is my understanding that he wants the button in a DIFFERENT application - which he created and has the source code for - to trigger a GUI event in the application that was injected. So there is no "properly setting up events" to be done in the target application, except by the DLL that is injected acquiring the event handle and waiting for it.

Comment: @Gerald: Now that I come to think of it, you might well be right. The question is however very poorly formulated.

Comment: If he has the source for the other program, then this will work, yes. Your answer is not incorrect. However, if he can modify the source, there are better ways and DLL injection shouldn't be used (except in a few testing-related edge cases, perhaps). Considering the context of game trainers given in the comments (which might have been after your post), it seems unlikely he can modify the original app from source, so hooks become necessary.

Comment: @peachykeen: Obviously there are 3 parties involved instead of 2: The injected process (the game), the DLL (which does something within the game process) and a third executable whose purpose is to act as an communication interface between the user and the injected DLL (the UI of the trainer).

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Why do you assume that the UI of the trainer can not be implemented within the trainer itself? In fact, this is the common case.

Comment: @Peachykeen... I'm pretty sure what he's trying to do is create a game trainer, with an external program that will control the behavior in the trainer (i.e. enable it or disable it.) If that is the case, then obviously he will have the source code for the application that will do the controlling.

Comment: @Mike: Why do *I* assume? You should ask that the OP. This whole misunderstanding happened because peachykeen and me didn't see why the OP had an additional EXE at all. But I doubt the questioner really put as much thought into that whole thing than we all did by now.

Comment: @Gerald That seems it could be the case, although why you would inject back into your own UI and hook that is beyond me. Typically you'd want the stub in the game with a hook to the game button, and then IPC to your UI, but I suspect Niklas is right in we've thought this out more than the OP.

Comment: There is no need to IPC to your UI. You can have the DLL spawn the UI. The added complexity of this IPC is what makes this method unattractive to game hackers even though it is used from time to time.

Comment: @Bawss: As Mike said, you could implement the GUI in the DLL and just use the external EXE as a loader. You wouldn't need IPC then (which is pretty hard to get right for a beginner).

Comment: Game Trainers are usually compiled as DLL which is too common now, I wanted my Game Trainer to be compiled as an EXE. And too make it less of an hassle (DLL: You have to run an injector and inject it into a process. But with EXE: Simply click to run it)

Comment: @MikeKwan That leaves the UI hosted within the target game, so you need to at least spawn another thread for it. I personally prefer to write the UI seperately, although I don't use IPC as such. Regardless, I would suggest the OP do some research into how such things work and the various methods.

Comment: @Bawss: Still the argument holds. I think the problem here is that you associated GUI with EXE. DLLs also execute code, so you can absolutely spawn a window out of the DLL.

Comment: @peachykeen you still haven't understood. He's not injecting back into his own UI. His UI is a simple application with a button, that is completely separate from the game. Nothing is being injected into that application. The DLL is being injected into a game, and he wants to trigger the DLL to execute some code in the game by clicking the button in his simple external application.

Comment: @Gerald If you edit your post, I can remove the downvote, since it seems to have been a correct answer to one of the original questions. *Edit:* If that is the case, then the UI and the DLL-in-game will be in different processes.

Comment: @Peachykeen I will take your advise :). Thanks everyone for time and your help (I REALLY APPRECIATE IT)! My first time here and this website is good so far - cause of you guys.

Comment: Oh I got another question, I've been making game cheats for awhile now but I never fully understand if its illegal or legal to make and sell game cheats?

Comment: @Peachykeen... what do I need to edit? "You need to communicate between your EXE and the application your DLL has been injected into." and "Then in your EXE, when your button is clicked, you set the event." seems pretty clear to me that the UI and DLL are in separate processes.

Comment: The UI and DLL are indeed separate processes.

Comment: @Bawss: It depends on the license agreement of the game and on your local law, but in every case I know of it's absolutely illegal ;)

Comment: @Gerald You don't need to edit any particular thing, the vote is just locked, so I can't change it without *some* edit.

Comment: @Bawss You're going to end up in a world of fun, definitely check out the projects I posted earlier (or we could probably drop into chat, though not sure how to make a room-from-comments). The legality is very complex, and we aren't lawyers here. I usually do graphics mods with this, which companies don't mind, but cheats may be a different matter.

Comment: @Bawss: I that case you'd better run before they get you.

Comment: Rule of thumb is if it's multiplayer, don't (or ask the developers). Even graphics work can set off Valve Anti-Cheat and Punkbuster, although they have exceptions for a lot of projects. If it's cheats and multiplayer, you could run against the EULA or it actually be illegal.

Comment: Yes: I am making a game trainer. I am planning to create the EXE to be the UI and the DLL to execute the cheats, bots, & etc.

Comment: @Bawss: Common sense should tell you that this cannot be what the makers of this game want (especially because it's multiplayer). So beware of consequences, especially if you plan to sell this stuff (if you actually ever get it to work).

Comment: I am doing it for educational purposes! ;)

Comment: If you're interested in learning about hooking and code modding in general, I would be happy to discuss it and give some links in a chat; I find it quite fun. However, I can't help you cheat for profit, and I believe that's against the site's ToS as well.

Comment: Whether it's legal or not is a gray area. Somebody using a cheat is a violation of the contract they agree to when they install and run a game, and apparently some judge a few years back ruled that selling cheats amounts to inciting people to break their contracts, and they can sue you for that. But it has only been successfully done in court once.

Comment: I have previously hacked MapleStory and would advise against it if you truly are doing it for **educational** purposes. If your aim is to learn reverse engineering, you will be deterred by the anti-cheat system. There are measures to prevent the trivial insertion of instrumentation such as CRCs as well as means to prevent loading of DLLs. You will be spending more time subverting the protection system than coding cheats. For educational purposes, you would be better off cheating a single-player game.